# jQuery read and outoput JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I have this this feed from Yahoo (YQL) and need to output some info to a webpage. Can someone help please. Thanks!! This is causing me severe headaches. lol

```
cbfunc({
 "query": {
  "count": "1",
  "created": "2010-12-07T10:38:18Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "quote": {
    "symbol": "^FTSE",
    "Ask": null,
    "AverageDailyVolume": "0",
    "Bid": null,
    "AskRealtime": null,
    "BidRealtime": null,
    "BookValue": null,
    "Change_PercentChange": "+67.33 - +1.17%",
    "Change": "+67.33",
    "Commission": null,
    "ChangeRealtime": "+67.33",
    "AfterHoursChangeRealtime": "N/A - N/A",
    "DividendShare": null,
    "LastTradeDate": "12/7/2010",
    "TradeDate": null,
    "EarningsShare": null,
    "ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid": "N/A",
    "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
    "EPSEstimateNextYear": null,
    "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": null,
    "DaysLow": "5769.67",
    "DaysHigh": "5838.52",
    "YearLow": "4790.04",
    "YearHigh": "5902.11",
    "HoldingsGainPercent": "- - -",
    "AnnualizedGain": "-",
    "HoldingsGain": null,
    "HoldingsGainPercentRealtime": "- - -",
    "HoldingsGainRealtime": null,
    "MoreInfo": "cnv",
    "OrderBookRealtime": "N/A",
    "MarketCapitalization": null,
    "MarketCapRealtime": null,
    "EBITDA": null,
    "ChangeFromYearLow": null,
    "PercentChangeFromYearLow": null,
    "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime": "5:20am - <b>5837.61</b>",
    "ChangePercentRealtime": "+67.33 - +1.17%",
    "ChangeFromYearHigh": null,
    "PercebtChangeFromYearHigh": null,
    "LastTradeWithTime": "5:20am - <b>5837.61</b>",
    "LastTradePriceOnly": "5837.61",
    "HighLimit": null,
    "LowLimit": null,
    "DaysRange": "5769.67 - 5838.52",
    "DaysRangeRealtime": "5769.67 - 5838.52",
    "FiftydayMovingAverage": null,
    "TwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
    "ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
    "PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage": null,
    "ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": null,
    "PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage": null,
    "Name": "FTSE 100",
    "Notes": "-",
    "Open": "5770.28",
    "PreviousClose": "5770.28",
    "PricePaid": null,
    "ChangeinPercent": "+1.17%",
    "PriceSales": null,
    "PriceBook": null,
    "ExDividendDate": "N/A",
    "PERatio": null,
    "DividendPayDate": "N/A",
    "PERatioRealtime": null,
    "PEGRatio": null,
    "PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear": null,
    "PriceEPSEstimateNextYear": null,
    "Symbol": "^FTSE",
    "SharesOwned": null,
    "ShortRatio": null,
    "LastTradeTime": "5:20am",
    "TickerTrend": "N/A",
    "OneyrTargetPrice": null,
    "Volume": "0",
    "HoldingsValue": null,
    "HoldingsValueRealtime": null,
    "YearRange": "4790.04 - 5902.11",
    "DaysValueChange": "- - +1.17%",
    "DaysValueChangeRealtime": "- - +1.17%",
    "StockExchange": "FSI",
    "DividendYield": null,
    "PercentChange": "+1.17%"
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your Q? this may help you http://lanitdev.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/using-jquery-and-yql-to-get-an-rss-feed-from-a-site/

Comment: what would u like to output? Could you be more specific and clarify what you want to do pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer after 2 days of head wrecking. Can't believe it. Here is the code. It was just to output data from YQL query for the FTSE 100. Thanks for answering everyone!

```
<div id="finance"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON(

"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%5EFTSE%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=?", 

function(json){
  $('#finance').text(json.query.results.quote.Change);  
    // Patching payload into page element ID = "dog"
});


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) : Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

[jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) : Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to output exactly? If this is a valid JSON object in string format you can use...

```
var obj = eval(JSON);
```

Where `JSON` is the feed you are receiving from Yahoo.

You can then access properties on the object eg.

```
var queryCount = obj.query.count;
```